# Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration-sftp

Not able to send the files to SFTP server. I didn't find the exact issue from the logs see below. used **Spring integration SFTP configuration** to send my files to client instance. I have referred this link https://blog.pavelsklenar.com/spring-integration-sftp-upload-example/ for implementation. what i m doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

below is the code snippet

```
DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(sftpHost);
        factory.setPort(sftpPort);
        factory.setUser(sftpUser);
        factory.setPassword(sftpPasword);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
```

see the logs below

```
    10-12-2018 03:03:22.261 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.promptYesNo - The authenticity of host 'example.com' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is d1:e9:4e:64:a8:e5:19:46:7a:0e:79:2d:bf:27:cb:4c.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting?
10-12-2018 03:03:22.264 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.promptYesNo - No UserInfo provided - The authenticity of host 'example.com' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is d1:e9:4e:64:a8:e5:19:46:7a:0e:79:2d:bf:27:cb:4c.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting?, returning:true
10-12-2018 03:03:22.265 [task-scheduler-1] WARN  com.jcraft.jsch.log - Permanently added 'example.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
10-12-2018 03:03:22.269 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch.log - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
10-12-2018 03:03:22.270 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch.log - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
10-12-2018 03:03:22.280 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch.log - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
10-12-2018 03:03:22.306 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch.log - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
10-12-2018 03:03:22.308 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.showMessage - SSH Server supporting SFTP and SCP

10-12-2018 03:03:22.337 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch.log - Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
10-12-2018 03:03:22.338 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch.log - Next authentication method: publickey
10-12-2018 03:03:22.342 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch.log - Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
10-12-2018 03:03:22.349 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch.log - Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
10-12-2018 03:03:22.425 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch.log - Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
10-12-2018 03:03:22.859 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.rename - File: CONVERGE_20181013.zip.writing was successfully renamed to CONVERGE_20181013.zip
10-12-2018 03:03:22.861 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch.log - Disconnecting from example.com port 22
10-12-2018 03:03:22.866 [Connect thread example.com session] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch.log - Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
```

Comment: Let me know if needed anymore details

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. Did you find the solution?

Comment: yes I have resolved it, by passing the remote directory dynamically. hope you resolved it